# Read Persian (Unicode chars) text file using php

Tags: php, utf-8, fopen, fread

I am reading one Persian text file (using PHP) with the help of below code:

```
/* Reading the file name and the book (UTF-8) */
if(file_exists($SourceDirectoryFile))
{
        $NameBook  = "name.txt";
        $AboutBook = "about.txt";

        $myFile = "Computer-Technolgy/2 ($i)/".$NameBook;
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
        $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
        fclose($fh);
        echo 'Name file: '. $theData.'<hr/>';
}
```

name.txt file contents :

```
آموزش شبكه هاي کامپيوتري (LEARNING NETWORK)
```

Name file: ����� ���� ��� ��������� (LEARNING NETWORK)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this is because you are just echoing the contents raw. Your browser will need more information, in order to display the message in its correct form.

The easiest way is to use the snippet below.

```
/* Reading the file name and the book (UTF-8) */
if (file_exists($SourceDirectoryFile))
{

    $NameBook  = "name.txt";
    $AboutBook = "about.txt";

    // Using file_get_contents instead. Less code
    $myFile   = "Computer-Technolgy/2 ($i)/" . $NameBook;
    $contents = file_get_contents($myFile);

    // I want my browser to display UTF-8 characters
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    echo 'Name file: ' .  $contents . '<hr/>';
}
```

Please note that the `header` function needs to be executed at the beginning of the output to the browser. So for instance if you have additional data that is displayed prior to this function, you need to move the header statement at the top. Otherwise you will end up with warnings on screen that the headers have already been set.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/me/public_html/books/documents/MoveFile.php:10) in /home/me/public_html/books/documents/MoveFile.php on line 45
Name file: ????? ???? ??? ????????? (LEARNING NETWORK)

Comment: This is what I wrote in my last paragraph. If your script outputs data on screen BEFORE the above snippet, you need to move the headers(...) function before that output. Check where the first output happens in your script and move that headers(...) declaration before it.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/me/public_html/books/documents/MoveFile.php:10) in /home/me/public_html/books/documents/MoveFile.php on line 42
Name file: ����� ���� ��� ��������� (LEARNING NETWORK)

Comment: Check your script. Find where you set the headers for your application. This could very well be a template where you define something like "<html><head>...." etc. IF you have such setup, add in the <head> section this: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> and remove the headers(..) function. If you are just printing text on the screen, find the line of code that does the first echo on your screen and put the headers(..) function above it.

Comment: Remove html tags in the page and I'll just tag php, the problem was solved
 Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure that the page where you're displaying the text file has [correct encoding](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html).

Comment: I've used the above <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//FA" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

Answer (score 0):

final and best solution is this:
use this line under your connect

```
mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');
```

like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","amirahmad","shoutit");
mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');
```

and at the end add this line right under the head tag in your  html to make sure your page have utf-8 charset,like this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and that's it . you can read formal document here : [pph.net charset](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php)