# Reading From Arabic File using php but the arabic syntax are converted?

Tags: php, arabic, readfile

I'm reading from a tab delimited file using php.
the first column of the file is written with arabic language

here is my code:

```
$fr=fopen("motor.txt", "r");
$contents = fread ($fr,filesize ("motor.txt"));
fclose ($fr);
$newline ="\n";
$sc = explode($newline, $contents);
echo $sc[1];
```

here is the line i read:
    LBP 10,000.00   575 12  89  77       براهيم الراسي

but  the output is:
    LBP 10,000.00   575 12  89  77  '(1'GJE 'D1'3J

Comment: The text files `.txt` don't allow that type of characters.

Comment: where are you showing the output(terminal, browser, ...)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read Persian (Unicode chars) text file using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588647/read-persian-unicode-chars-text-file-using-php)